# Wordpress auto-update install permissions

Tags: apache2, chmod, wordpress, ownership

I use Kubuntu 17.04 with Apache2, Mysql and PHP7 to run Wordpress test for testing purposes. I use NetBeans editor to edit files on the server.

When I installed I was facing "non writable directory" when trying to auto-update WP to newer version, so Ive set group to `www-data`. It fixed, but it was not editable by NetBeans, so Ive set it to `chmod 777`.

Ive also tried FTP, but I don't want to run another service on my laptop and connect each time I make changes.

I know it's not the best practise to have chmod 777 even for localhost testing. Is there any other way to keep the `/var/www/` writeable for NetBeans (and other utilities) and Wordpress at once?

Thanks